# WordPress: Theme Migration

Tags: wordpress, export, themes, wordpress-theming, migrate

I'm trying to help move a website, and I copied a clean version of the twentyfourteen themes from spot A into spot B, but it did not take effect.

Our site (as mentioned earlier) had been injected, so we're relocating our site with a fresh install. On the original WordPress site export did not work properly for the pages, so I do not think it would work for a theme.

Does anyone had any tricks they'd like to share?
Thank you!

Comment: Activate it in the admin?

Comment: I made sure the theme was active... but still held no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original theme seems to be stuck as the active theme in your database. Do you have any plugins running yet? ...More specifically a plugin that can cache your site?
If there aren't any plugins running, it's probably stuck in your server's cache and needs a bit of time to roll over.

Comment: I saw something about the database while researching. I didn't move the database into the new location yet. So if I drop the theme back into place (because I did revert it), and try refreshing the DB cache, will it knock it into order?

Comment: Kinna T, or anyone else, how does one refresh the database cache? Thanks!

Comment: To add to this answer, it also was a missing main.css file we use. Double check any existing links for the website! I found out when I opened the page in a browser, and viewed source. It told me what it could not locate.

Comment: Sorry about the delay! There's not a simple way to refresh the database cache other than a graceful server restart. I'm glad you located what you needed! To give a clear picture to anyone who needs this in the future: Yes, migrating the database would bring all of your main settings and such into line, though your theme options will likely be lost. Be careful with a database migration and make sure you do your research on which tables should go with and which can be excluded.

I recommend a database migration tool that's specifically made for WordPress if you aren't 100% on this.